# Copy array by indexing cell numbers

Tags: matlab

I am trying to extract specific columns from a "nested" array, the columns I need are nested, there are about a thousand columns, of which I only need the ones marked by index in another part of the array.

I have one Array{1,15} containing cells with numerical values (e.g. 2,5,10,53). These values are the index numbers i need to extract from another array.

```
indexnum = OutArray{1,15}(:);
```

Which arranges them in a column instead of a row, totally not necessary but seemed easier for me to progress with this.

Then I have the array containing the actual columns I want to extract/copy to a new array.

```
OutArray{1,14}{i,1}
```

So by the example numbers above, I need to copy column 2,5,10 and 53 to another array.

One of my more current attempts looks like this:

```
NewArray = []; %create new array
indexnum = OutArray{1,15}(:); %copy right index values to column
for i = indexnum{:} %use numeric value of every cell
NewArray = [NewArray, OutArray{1,14}{1,i}] %copy corresponding columns to NewArray
end
```

I also tried to use cell2mat(indexnum(1,:)), but that didn't help either.

To make clear the structure of the array:

- OutArray{1,15} Contains cells with 1 value per column, which are index numbers for other array
- OutArray{1,14} contains nested cells, 1 cell per column
- OutArray{1,14}{1,x} contains columns with ~30 values per column, of which I want to copy the columns with the right indexes

For another array in which I just needed to copy all columns this code worked fine:

```
new1 = [];
for i = 1:length(OutArray{1,4})
new1 = [new1, OutArray{1,4}{i,1}]
end
```

Comment: Can I see how your Array{1,15} looks like? I read this two times and I'm still confused.

Comment: Yes, i included screenshots of all relevant arrays, in case there is more of my description that might not make perfect sense.
[link to image on imgur](https://imgur.com/a/Hz8XR)

Comment: It is a bit confusing. In some places you have `{1,i}`, and in others `{i,1}`. It would also be useful to say what error you are getting, or why does it not work? you get the wrong columns?

Comment: Ah yes, that is an error, it's supposed to be {i,1} all the way, it originates in trying minor tweaks.
The error i get for the above code is:
"Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object."

Comment: I also encountered:
- subsindex error (because i used () instead of {})
- Expected one output from curly brace/dot indexing but got X results (because i tried: for i = indexnum{:})
- Error using cell2mat. Too many input arguments. (When trying: for i = cell2mat(colx{:}) )

Comment: The screenshots  were very helpful to understand the question but next time please edit your answers to add that information instead of using the comments. That way people can see them directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bit hard to understand because of so many cells into cells but your screenshots were very helpful. I will first highlight the errors and needed changes in your attemp:

```
NewArray = []; %create new array
indexnum = OutArray{1,15}(:); %copy right index values to column
for i = indexnum{:} %use numeric value of every cell
NewArray = [NewArray, OutArray{1,14}{1,i}] %copy corresponding columns to NewArray
end
```

1. Doing  `OutArray{1,15}(:)` is exactly the same as `OutArray{1,15}` as you are just selecting the full cell of cells.
2. Your for loop uses `indexnum{:}` as the iterator but `{:}` returns a comma separated list and it does not work like `(:)` for arrays that give the full vector instead. In this case, when you assign `indexnum{:}` to a variable you get only the first element of the list. An example to ilustrate this:`C = {1, 2, 3}; C{:}` displays the full list, but `x = C{:}` only makes `x = 1`. To get all the elements you could group them in an array by doing: `x = [C{:}]`.
   So in your case you just need to add brackets to `for i = [indexnum{:}]` to get the iterator working.

To sum up, your code would be changed to:

```
NewArray = []; %create new array
indexnum = OutArray{1,15}; %copy right index values to column

for i = [indexnum{:}]
    NewArray = [NewArray, OutArray{1,14}{1,i}}];
end
```

In addition, you could avoid the for loop and variables initialization with this single line code:

```
NewArray = [OutArray{1,14}{1,[OutArray{1,15}{1,:}]}];
```

As you can see, it just takes row 1 of your data `OutArray{1,14}` and the columns specified at each element of the indexes `OutArray{1,15}`. Brackets are needed twice because when indexing a cell with curly braces with more than one index at a time you always get a list and need to convert into an array as explained above.

Comment: That's write, thanks. I was just trying to highlight the needed changes in his code to make it work. The second method I proposed does not need preallocation right?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Lidia! I've also found a solution while sitting in a train without internet:


    col_id = [];
    li_scan = [];
    col_id = OutArray{X,15}(:);
    for i = cell2mat(col_id(:,1))
    li_scan = [li_scan,OutArray{X,14}{1,i}]
    end


but of course your solution is way nicer than that :)

Comment: You are very welcome. Your solution is based in cell2mat that does essentially  the same as the brackets. Congrats for finding ir on your own. Be careful with the appending inside the loop!